# Как остановить цикл for при невыполнении условия внутри цикла?

Tags: php

Подскажите, есть ли возможность остановить цикл for, если при очередной итерации цикла разница между текущим и предыдущим значением НЕ равна 1. И как это сделать, в какую сторону хоть копать, потому что совсем запутался. Здесь на последней итерации цикла вычисляется разница 14 и 11, которая равна 3. Соответственно, я бы хотел реализовать такое поведение, чтобы после получения значения, не равного 1, цикл for прекращался и возвращалось бы значение false

```
<?php

function mmm($arr)
{
  if (count($arr) > 1) {
    for($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
      $final = $arr[$i] - $arr[$i - 1];
    }
  }
}

mmm([10, 11, 14]);
```

Comment: _получения значения, не равного 1, цикл for прекращался и возвращалось бы значение false_  `if ((int)$final !== 1) { return false }`

Comment: Для цикла for нужно делать вложенный if?

Comment: Да, сразу после _$final = ..._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
function mmm($arr)
{
    $return = true;
    if (count($arr) > 1) {
        for($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            $val = $arr[$i] - $arr[$i - 1];
            if($val != 1)
            {
                $return = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Отличная пища для размышлений и решение моего вопроса!

Comment: @SerG you welcome